# Horizantal bars not arranging in order

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom-bar, col

My R code:

```
1. df <- data.frame(table(mast$State))
2. df 
3. df <- df[order(df$Freq,decreasing = FALSE),]            
4. df
5. df1 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=Var1,y=Freq))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+coord_flip()
6. df1
```

> Line 1 - created new dataframe with freq table of variable 'State' in
>   original dataframe mast - worked fine
>
> Line 2 - executed df to view whether the output is correct - worked
>   fine
>
> Line 3 - arranged the frequency table in increasing order - worked
>   fine
>
> Line 4 - executed df again to check whether data is arranged in an
>   order - worked fine
>
> Line 5 - wanted horizontal bar for dataframe df with varaible
>   'State'arranged in an order - Not working

why the horizontal bars are not getting arranged in an order though in line 4 freq table was arranged in an order?
My final output is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEaEZ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

Comment: Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead.

Answer (score -1):

this should do:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(Var1, Freq), y = Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip()
```